# Verilog: Using parameter in if statement

Tags: verilog

How can I check for a parameter based value in an if statement?

I have a parametrized counter and I cannot find answers to how to check the max size i.e. e.g.

`if(count_val == WIDTH'b1) count_pulse = 1'b1;`

Any chance i could get some help :) ?

```
module counter #(
parameter WIDTH=3,
parameter DIR = 0

)(CLK, EN, RST, COUNT_VAL, COUNT_PULSE);

input CLK, EN, RST;
output [WIDTH:0] COUNT_VAL;
output COUNT_PULSE;

reg[WIDTH:0] count_val=0;
reg count_pulse;
always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
        if(RST == 1'b1) count_val <= 0;
        else if(EN == 1'b1) begin
            if(DIR == 1'b0) count_val <= count_val + 1;
            else if(DIR == 1'b1) count_val <= count_val - 1;
        if(count_val == WIDTH'b1) count_pulse = 1'b1;
        else count_pulse = 1'b0;
        end
    end

assign COUNT_VAL = count_val;
endmodule
```

Comment: Considering `WIDTH=3`, do you want it to compare with `3'b001` or `3'b111`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replication.

```
if(count_val == {WIDTH{1'b1}}) count_pulse = 1'b1;
```

or a shift

```
if(count_val == ((32'b1<<WIDTH)-1) count_pulse = 1'b1;
```

or in SystemVerilog, a bit fill

```
if(count_val == '1) count_pulse = 1'b1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have been trying to use `WIDTH'b1` should be translated to `3'b1` which is `001`. If this is the case, you do not really need the width specifier. The following will do:

```
if (counter_val == 1)
```

or to use precise widths:

```
if (counter_val == { {WIDTH-1{0}}, 1'b1} )
```

If you meant, `111`, the see dave_59's answer.